# How to select columns based on criteria in a certain row in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a matrix of values with both row names and column names, as shown here.

C5.Outliers

```
Days   J1      J2      J3      J4  
0.01   458    -160    -151    -52     
0.02   459    -163    -154    -46    
0.03   457    -165    -150    -51   
Perc   0.99   0.04    0.00    0.52
```

I would like to create a separate matrix using only the columns for which the value for the row "Perc" is =<50.0.  In this example, I would be extracting columns J2 and J3.

This is the code I tried which isn't working (the "Perc" row is row #1414 on my matrix): 
C5.Final<-subset(C5.Outliers, 1414<.51)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean 0.50 since all the columns with the "Perc" are above 50.0.

this might not be the best way but it works:

```
#data:
df <- data.frame(Days=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,"Perc"),J1=c(458,459,457,0.99),
J2 =c(-165,-163,-160,0.04),J3=c(-151,-153,-131,0.00),J4=c(-52,-45,-51,0.52))

dfc <- subset(df,,select= which(c(TRUE,(df[which(df$Days == "Perc"), ] <= 0.50)[2:5])))

dfc
  Days      J2   J3
1 0.01 -165.00 -151
2 0.02 -163.00 -153
3 0.03 -160.00 -131
4 Perc    0.04    0
```

You can remove the `TRUE,` if you dont want the `df$Days` variable, change the `0.50` threshold if needed and expand the `2:5` if you have extra columns or even substitute the `"Perc"` with `1414` if you so wish.

Hope this works.

Comment: I tried this approach, but this is the error message I get.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Comment: My actual code (assuming df=C5.Outliers and dfc=C5.Remove) was this. I want to run the analysis on the first 17 columns: C5.Remove <- subset(C5.Outliers,,select= which(c(TRUE,(C5.Outliers[which(C5.Outliers$Days == "Perc"), ] <= 0.50)[1:17])))

Comment: Also my first column was set to row names.

Comment: can i get some extra sample data, if you want 17 columns then you have to change the selected data, instead of `[2:5]` then `[2:17]` i surpose- again it helps if i got a minimal reproducable example. You can use the actual subset argument, `subset(dataset, Condition to select from data set, and then the columns) ` -  You can remove ronames with `rownames(df) <- NULL`

Comment: Ok thanks. Removing rownames solved part of my problem, but now I get the following error message instead: "In Ops.factor(left, right) : <= not meaningful for factors."  My exact code is in comment #2 (though after removing row names, I changed the extent to [2:17].)  Will add a larger example of the table, though other than extending it to 17 columns and 600 rows, there is not much that is different than what I displayed.

Comment: I decided to transpose the data since the subset function is much more straightforward this way.  My new question is posted as: "Subset function is not creating a subset of rows, but is instead changing values to zero"

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you meant `<= 0.50` and not `<= 50` since all "Perc" are less than 50.  You can do

```
df[, unlist(df["Perc",]) <= 0.5]
#           J2   J3
# 0.01 -160.00 -151
# 0.02 -163.00 -154
# 0.03 -165.00 -150
# Perc    0.04    0
```

But this may be safer and takes into account any `NA` values that may appear in "Perc".

```
u <- unlist(df["Perc",]) <= 0.50
df[, u & !is.na(u)]
```

Also, you can speed it up if need be by adding `use.names = FALSE` in `unlist()`.  And finally, if you have a matrix and not a data frame, then you can remove `unlist()` all together.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it did something different than what I am looking for.  It changed the values which were <0.5 in the percent column to "0." All the columns remained in the spreadsheet (it did not remove any of them for me)